# Using RANK() along with ROLLUP in Oracle SQL to rank grouped rows and summarize

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table of tasks, people and time I would like to be able to see the person who spent the most time on each task, how much time they spent on that task and a summary row below that.

Example table:

```
task        person  time
----        ------  ----
Admin       Sue     0.5
Admin       Ted     0.25
Meetings    Ted     1.25
Meetings    Sue     0.75
```

Desired outcome:

```
task        top_person
----        ----------
Admin       Sue (0.5)
Meetings    Ted (1.25)
Overall     Ted (1.5)
```

So we can see the top ranking person for each task as well as the top ranking person overall with their sum total time across all tasks.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT
    DECODE(GROUPING(task), 0, task, 'Overall') AS task,
    MAX(person || ' (' || time || ')') KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY time DESC) AS top_person
FROM time_table
GROUP BY ROLLUP(task)
```

Output:

```
task        top_person
----        ----------
Admin       Sue (0.5)
Meetings    Ted (1.25)
Overall     Ted (1.25)
```

This query groups the table by task, ranks the tasks within the group by time, keeps the first row, then displays the person and their time from the row that was kept. This works well except for the rollup line, it seems like this line is doing the same logic for the individual task groups except across all tasks. What I need instead is something like the sum of time across all tasks, grouped by person, ranked by hours, but only applied to the rollup line, not the others. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Can one person have more than one row for the same task? What name should be shown if two people have the same time for the same task?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider using [MODEL](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) clause for this kind of queries. It is quite convenient for inter row/column operations.
Sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl (TASK, PERSON, TASK_TIME) AS
        (
            Select 'Admin',     'Sue',    0.5     FRom Dual Union All
            Select 'Admin',     'Ted',   0.25     FRom Dual Union All
            Select 'Meetings',  'Ted',   1.25     FRom Dual Union All
            Select 'Meetings',  'Sue',   0.75     FRom Dual 
        )
```

SQL resulting as asked in the question:

```sql
Select *
From    ( Select      TASK_STR "TASK", PERSON_STR "TOP_PERSON"
          From    (   Select    CAST(TASK as Varchar2(20)) "TASK", 
                                CAST(TASK as Varchar2(20)) "TASK_STR",
                                CAST(PERSON as VarChar2(20)) "PERSON", 
                                TASK_TIME "TASK_TIME",
                                '(' || PERSON || ' ' || TASK_TIME || ')' "PERSON_STR" 
                      From tbl
                  )
              MODEL Dimension By (TASK, PERSON)
                    Measures(TASK_TIME, TASK_STR, PERSON_STR)
                    Rules (
                              TASK_STR[ANY, ANY] = Case When TASK_TIME[CV(), CV()] = Max(TASK_TIME)[CV(), ANY] Then CV(TASK) END, 
                              TASK_STR['Overall', 'Time'] = CV(TASK) || ' ' || CV(PERSON),
                              PERSON_STR['Overall', 'Time'] = Sum(TASK_TIME)[TASK != CV(), PERSON != CV()]
                          )
        )
Where TASK Is Not Null
UNION ALL Select 'Overall ' || PERSON "TASK", To_Char(Sum(TASK_TIME)) "TOP_PERSON" From tbl Group By PERSON  

R e s u l t :
TASK                 TOP_PERSON                                   
-------------------- ----------------------------------------------
Admin                (Sue .5)                                       
Meetings             (Ted 1.25)                                     
Overall Time         2.75                                           
Overall Sue          1.25                                           
Overall Ted          1.5
```

Changing the RULES part of a MODEL  clause could give you anything else you may need or want to get from your data:

```sql
... ... ...
              MODEL Dimension By (TASK, PERSON)
                    Measures(TASK_TIME, TASK_STR, PERSON_STR)
                    Rules (
                              TASK_STR[ANY, ANY] = Case When TASK_TIME[CV(), CV()] = Max(TASK_TIME)[CV(), ANY] Then CV(TASK) END, 
                              --
                              TASK_STR['Overall', 'Data'] = 'Overall Data Below',
                              PERSON_STR['Overall', 'Data'] = LPAD('-', 15, '-'),
                              --
                              TASK_STR['Time', 'Total'] = CV(TASK) || ' ' || CV(PERSON),
                              PERSON_STR['Time', 'Total'] = Sum(TASK_TIME)[TASK != CV(), PERSON != CV()],
                              --
                              TASK_STR['Rows', 'Count'] = 'Rows Count',
                              PERSON_STR['Rows', 'Count'] = Count(PERSON_STR)[TASK != CV() And TASK NOT IN('Overall', 'Time', 'Rows'), PERSON != CV() And PERSON NOT IN('Data', 'Total', 'Count', 'Average')],
                              --
                              TASK_STR['Time', 'Average'] = 'Time Average',
                              PERSON_STR['Time', 'Average'] = Avg(TASK_TIME)[TASK != CV() And TASK != 'Overall', PERSON != CV() And PERSON NOT IN('Data', 'Total', 'Count', 'Average')]
                          )
        )
Where TASK Is Not Null
Order By TASK

R e s u l t :  
TASK                 TOP_PERSON                                   
-------------------- ----------------------------------------------
Admin                (Sue .5)                                       
Meetings             (Ted 1.25)                                     
Overall Data Below   ---------------                                
Rows Count           4                                              
Time Average         .6875                                          
Time Total           2.75
```

Comment: Your Overall value is not matching with OP's requirement. May you please fix your model clause.

Answer (score 1):

Though Model clause works exceptionally well, But If you want more SQL specific solution, You can try -

```
WITH max_data AS (SELECT task, person, TASK_TIME,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY task ORDER BY TASK_TIME DESC) RN1
                    FROM your_table
                 ),
overall_person_data AS (SELECT person, SUM(TASK_TIME) sum_time
                          FROM your_table
                         GROUP BY person
                       )
SELECT task, person || '(' || TASK_TIME || ')'
  FROM max_data
 WHERE RN1 = 1
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Overall', MAX(person) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sum_time DESC) 
                  || '(' 
                  ||  MAX(sum_time) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY sum_time DESC)
                  || ')'
  FROM overall_person_data;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/X1NCkOCU)

Comment: There is something wrong with your code @Ankit Bajpai, I'm afraid. First union selects data from max_data where is no column named max_time. The  second unioned query selects data from max_data again selecting MAX(sum_time) where sum_time does not exist. It is in another cte named overall_person_data.  There are more issues. Could you check it, please?

Comment: @dr, Thank you so much for pointing it out. I have updated my answer. I think its better if you can remove your code as it seems incorrect now. Infact your query result is wrong. The overall value is not matching with OP's requirement.

Comment: Removed the edit. My model clause answer is here for the OP to consider as a much wider possibility. Model clause is adjustable, reliable and, in my experience, very fast. Results are intentionaly like the labels describe them - not like asked. Someone may / should adjust it to whatever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: write {1} a query for the "details" part of the required result set, and {2} another query for the "overall" part of the result set, and use UNION for combining the 2 parts.  A VIEW will help to use the queries easily.

**Table & data**

```
create table tasks( task, person, time )
as
select 'Admin',     'Sue',    0.5     from dual union all
select 'Admin',     'Ted',   0.25     from dual union all
select 'Meetings',  'Ted',   1.25     from dual union all
select 'Meetings',  'Sue',   0.75     from dual 
;
```

**Query 1 (details)**

```
select task, person, time,
  dense_rank() over ( partition by task order by time desc ) rank_
from tasks ;

-- result
TASK     PERSON  TIME   RANK_
Admin    Sue     .5     1
Admin    Ted     .25    2
Meetings Ted     1.25   1
Meetings Sue     .75    2
```

**Query 2 (overall)**

```
select person, sum_
, dense_rank() over ( order by sum_ desc ) rank_
from (
  select person
  , sum( time ) sum_
  from tasks
  group by person
) ;

-- result
PERSON  SUM_    RANK_
Ted     1.5     1
Sue     1.25    2
```

Now that we have 2 subsets containing "ranked" rows, we just need to
write WHERE clauses that will filter the results (only returning rows whose rank_ equals 1). It is an advantage to add a column containing a hard-coded "section" value to the queries, so that we can reliably ORDER the result sets of the queries. (Notice that both Query 1 and Query 2 are part of the VIEW.  The above sections are just illustrating the inner workings of the view.)

**View**

```
create or replace view taskperson_view
as
select 1 as section, task, person, time
from ( 
-- --------------------------------------------------------- query 1
  select task, person, time,
    dense_rank() over ( partition by task order by time desc ) rank_
  from tasks
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
)
where rank_ = 1
  union
select 2, 'Overall', person, sum_
from ( 
-- --------------------------------------------------------- query 2
  select person, sum_
  , dense_rank() over ( order by sum_ desc ) rank_
  from (
    select person
    , sum( time ) sum_
    from tasks
    group by person
  )
-- ---------------------------------------------------------
)
where rank_ = 1
;
```

Once the view is in place, just write a simpler query, and apply all the formatting and ordering of the final result.

**Query & finishing touches**

```
select 
  task
, person || ' (' || to_char( time, 'FM90.99' ) || ')' as top_person
from taskperson_view
order by section 
;

-- result
TASK            TOP_PERSON
Admin           Sue (0.5)
Meetings        Ted (1.25)
Overall         Ted (1.5)
```

[Link to DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R-OGdtD-).